# after downloading/installing android SDK, the folder in win7 is readonly

Tags: android

After downloading/installing Android SDK, it put the files/folders here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`

if I right click on the parent folder, Android, I see that it's readonly. I unchecked readonly, and I got a prompt saying, "`You will need to provide adminitsrator permission to change these attributes`". I clicked Continue. It then seemed to run thru that folder and all of its children, applying the new non-readonly attr.

But when I right click on the Android folder and go to props again, it says it's readonly again.

Can anyone help w/ this? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you accept? Will not it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Win7 has a lot of access problems when you install some programs in the Program Files(x86)

Uninstall the android sdk and install it in C:/ for example, it will work.

Comment: I just installed in `C:\Android\android-sdk` without problems

Answer (score 1):

It seems Windows 7 is very strict (junk) on these rights. Even though I login as admin, still I get this message. May be what you can do is, right click--->properties--Security tab--> add you as owner and try.

Answer (score 0):

Just move it to your desktop, thats what I did with mine. (if that doesn't work uninstall and install to your desktop/download the zip)

Answer (score 0):

Google the problem. About a year ago I had similar problems with Windows 7 security. Windows 7 sets certain system files (and any that you put below protected folders) to be owned at a system level that's not deletable by administrators. It's a way to prevent viruses from modifying system files, etc. At least that was the logic I was told.

There's a process that you can use to acquire ownership of the files and then be able to delete them. I have forgotten the commands and the procedure, but it's available on the internet...